# Combobox LinkedCell as Percentage when selecting an item

Tags: vba, excel, combobox

I have an `Active X Combo box` with a list of percentages 10%, 20% etc. 
When I choose a value in, the `Combo Box` (30%) the value of the `ComboBox` becomes "0.3". So the `LinkedCell` receives the value "0.3".

When I enter a percentage manually as a value for the `Combobox` (eg "30%"), the `LinkedCell` retrieves the same value ("30%") (The cell format is `Text`).

How can i get it to show 10%, 20%, etc in the `LinkedCell` when I choose an item in the Dropdown?

[image]

**Recommanded solution** :

I tried changing the format as recommanded for this issue everywhere but it does not solve the problem.

```
Private Sub ComboBox3_Change()
ComboBox3.Value = Format(ComboBox3.Value, "0.0%")
End Sub
```

Moreover the result is incoherent :

[image]

**How I populate the Combobox :**

The `ListFillRange` of the `Combobox` (Developer->Properties) is a `Range` (Formulas->Name Manager) of percentages that I entered directly in the Sheet.
[image]

Comment: Have you also formatted your linked cell?

Comment: Yes as I mentionned its format is `Text`. So if I force manually a value (30%) to the Combobox, the LinkedCell retrieves the good format (30%) with no problem.

Comment: Format the linked cell as a %. This works for me with your change code.

Comment: I tried it as well but it still retrieves the value as "0.3". Moreover the value displayed in the `Combobox` becomes "0,2%" when choosing "30%" due to the code which is incoherent.

Comment: I notice there is no linked cell in your picture above - is that definitely set up correctly.

Comment: Yes I corrected it thanks

Answer (score 0):

I can't elaborate in a comment so this is the set up I used. The source range is "Fred" - 10%/20%/30%, the linked cell is E1, formatted as % and I used your change code. When I update the combobox E1 changes as in the picture.

[image]

Comment: With the same code I get "0%" as value in the `Combobox` everytime I select an item, and in the `LinkedCell` it displays the good item but in this format "0.1"

Comment: Try setting that up in a new workbook from scratch and see if it works. Perhaps other code is interfering.

Comment: Good idea, I tried starting a new one from scratch but the problem persists. (I updated with new screenshots) Do you have Excel 2016 as well?

Comment: Have a look at your system separators, do you have , for decimal? Your combobox will show 0.1 (but in that case you'll need 0,1 for 10%). Use .list or AddItem to fill your ComboBox, not ListFillrange

Comment: Yes that could be the issue @EvR. Takichiii - your screenshots have changed and you now appear to have a comma separator.

Comment: Thank you for your time, I was just about to comment that it's now working and I don't know why, but then again it started always displaying 0% when `ComboBox1.Value = Format(ComboBox1.Value, "0%")`. I'm very confused I think it's a bug related to `ActiveX` component

Comment: ActiveX is very buggy so you are better off using Forms controls if possible.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the VB code to the ComboBox solved my problem.  I now get the "%" shown on both the list items and the value in the linked cell.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).